# Vuejs - Use variable for background-image in style template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have got a question regarding using a variable within the background-image of the style template. Is this possible at all?

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
 <script>
  export default {
    name: 'setCss',
    computed: {
    cssVars() {
      var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
      var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
      var path = '';
      if(isAndroid) {
        path = 'img/samsung/';
      } else{
        path = 'img/iphone/';
      }
      return {
        '--bg-path': path,
      }
    }
    }
  };
</script>
```

and then with this CSS:

```
    <style scoped>
div {
    background-image: var(--bg-path) + '/1366x400@2x.jpg';
    background-size: 1366px 400px;
}

@media not all,
not all,
only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    div {
        background-image: var(--bg-path) + '/480x288.jpg';
        background-size: 480px 288px;
    }
}

</style>
```

This will not work but I am wondering if there is a way to do this?

Comment: move the `background-image:` part out of css and do it in vue, or actually set the css var --bg-path `document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--bg-path', path)`. where and how are you using `cssVars`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use [class/style binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html).

In your case, binding style would look something like the following. First, you would need to bind a style with the computed background image (the rest of the styles don't need to be bound, they can remain in your `style` tag).

```html
<template>
 <div :style="{backgroundImage: computedBgImage}"></div>
</template>
```

```js
...
computed:{
  computedBgImage() {
      let path;
      if (isAndroid) {
        path = 'img/samsung/';
      } else{
        path = 'img/iphone/';
      }
     return path + '/480x288.jpg'
  }
}
...
```

If you need to use the same image in multiple places, consider defining a class for each image, and binding the class, instead of the style, as explained in the above link.

Answer (score 2):

For this to work, you will simply need to pass the computed property `cssVars` to the component as dynamic `style` attribute like:

```
<button :style="cssVars">My button</button>
```

**Here is a working demo:**
(*here I am passing a hardcoded value for `bgColor`, but you can assume that being passed as a prop to a component also*)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#myApp",
  data: {
    bgColor: "green"
  },
  computed: {
    cssVars() {
      return {
        '--bg-color': this.bgColor,
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
button {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  padding:10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="myApp">
  <button :style="cssVars">My button</button>
</div>
```